# Getting "Cookie “PHPSESSID” has been rejected for invalid domain." on console when one module calls another

Tags: php

I have an application that, at one point, uses an href in a menu list to call a secure page.  The calling module uses $_SESSION variables but they get lost causing the called module to fail and I see the message, above, in my debug console.  I use "session_start()" correctly.

Any ideas???

Comment: Does this help ? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#125241

Comment: Are the two "modules" on different domains, or sub-domains? One on plain-text http:// and one on secure https:// ?

Comment: No BUT the second is in a sub-directory.  In xxx.com/aaa.php I href to xxx.com/yyy/zzz.php and the cookies and the session variables fo away but the session id is the same in both!!!  I just discovered another example of the same behavior.  I am not sure if it is a php.ini issue or a host server issue.  When I moved zzz.php to the same directory as aaa.php it works.  DUH!!!  Is a subdirectory considered another domain?